# Set a MailItem as sent before calling SaveAs in Outlook Addin with C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am building an Outlook 2010 addin to integrate it with some business software and have trapped the ItemSend Event. I check if it is a MailItem and if it is I call the SaveAs function to save it as a .msg to the file system (in the users temp folder).

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if(Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        string filename = "somefilename.msg";
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
        string fullPathName = path+filename;
        mailitem.SaveAs(fullPathName, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
    }
}
```

I go on to read the file contents and send the file to the server using webservices. It all works fine.

The issue I have is if I go and open the file that it saves, then Outlook opens it as a message still being composed and the user could very easily click the Send button again.

Is there a way to flag that the item has been sent before it gets saved so when opened after the fact it opens as a readable email rather than an in-composition email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.debugging.com/bug/22915#79238) (and additionally at the last answer on that page), this might help you.

(Makes use of [ItemAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb220152.aspx) event)

Comment: So capture it as it gets moved to the sent items and then save it? I hadn't thought of that. Thanks. :)

Comment: In other words: Instead of using the Application.ItemSend event, you can use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder - by that time the message will be in the sent state.